# Getting URL(URI) address from Web Browser

Tags: c#, wpf, file, uri

I am trying to get the URL string (uri) in the WebBrowser component after navigation, but the returned address is incomplete.

---

It should look like "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html#access_token=..." but

```
e.Uri.AbsoluteUri
```

and all other fields return only "https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html" ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddGHE.png))

A line beyond the "#" is not returned. I navigate to the address in the browser, everything is displayed normally. I didn't find the answer to this question anywhere, I hope, here will help me.

I tried to get the URL in different ways but failed to get the full string.

---

Here's an code example:

```
browser.Navigate(getTokenUrl);
browser.Navigated += (sender, e) =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript

Window.location.href will return all the url including hash part.

You can use apis to run this JavaScript in browser component and it should return you correct url.

The api to run JavaScript depends on browser component you are using.

Comment: Nope. Same problem.

Code:


    `var doc = (HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
    MessageBox.Show("RESULT: " + doc.parentWindow.location.href);`


Result: [image](https://i.imgur.com/3yfjok6.png)

Comment: I also tried using javascript code `doc.parentWindow.execScript("alert(document.location.href)");` directly, the result is the same.

Comment: Use window.location.href in JavaScript instead of document location.   If that does not work the check if location.hash retuns the part after hash

Comment: In the browser, the location.hash is returned correctly, but in the WebBrowser component hash is still empty